# Как при выполнении 2 событий выполнить одну функцию

Tags: javascript, функции, события

У меня есть ползунок, который должен активировать функцию JS. Пользователь может увести сам курсор с ползунка, но продолжая тянуть ползунок, зажав левую кнопку мыши, но когда передвинув ползунок в нужное место пользователь отпустит левую кнопку мыши уже не на ползунке, а где-то в рандомной точке экрана, то функция не сработает, по этому варианты с `$(document).click` отпадают.

Написал следующий вариант, возможно какой-то колхозный, но все же для примера:

```
$(document).on('mousedown', '#id', function (){
    $(window).click(function (){ 
        // Код всей функции
    }
}
```

Теперь столкнулся с проблемой, что при первой загрузке страницы все хорошо, код работает как надо, но при повторном действии функция начинает уже работать при клике в любой точке экрана, игнорируя это `$(document).on('mousedown', '#id', function ()` Как сделать чтоб эти 2 события работали по принципу

```
if(условия1 && условие2){
 //Выполняю
}
```

P.S. `$(window).click(function ()` применял специально, что улавливать клик даже если пользователь увел курсор с ползунка.

Comment: фактически у вас тут нет двух условий, у вас при клике в кнопку назначается событие на весь документ.

Comment: Если у ползунка всего два положения (типа вкл\выкл.), я бы просто дал ползунку возможность меняться по клику, а не перетаскиванием.

Comment: @НиколайГабараев, ползунок выбирает значение, от 1 до N-ого

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это происходит потому, что вы при первом событии 'mousedown' назначаете обработчик на click всего окна. Используйте 'mouseup' события, предварительно запомнив на каком элементе был 'mousedown'

Перемещение ползунка не добавляю, но пример основную идею должен отобразить:

```js
$(function() {
  var isMousDownOnSlider = false;

  $('.slider').on('mousedown', function(event) {
    isMousDownOnSlider = true;
  });

  $(document).on('mouseup', function(event) {
    if (isMousDownOnSlider) {
      console.log('Slider mouse up');
      isMousDownOnSlider = false;
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.slider {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: green
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider"></div>
```

Comment: Можете показать пример? Буду очень благодарен.

Comment: Добавил пример.

Comment: В моем варианте лучше подошел вместо `$(document).on('mouseup', function(event)` вот это `$(window).click`.